# how to insert big data to mysql limit by nusoap only 30 second

Tags: php, mysql, nusoap

I have thousand of data from an webservice .
but nusoap limit execution time only 30 second .
I can't insert all those data because of this limit .
I can't change nusoap setting because is on server .
.
is there anyway to fix that ?
.
EDIT 1
i tried split big data to array chunk, but after 30 second is over
here's my code (using code igniter)

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$_datas = array_chunk($data["result"], 300);
foreach ($_datas as $key => $data) {
$insert=$this->db->insert_batch('temp_mahasiswa', $data);
if (!$insert && $this->db->error()) {
     //some logics here, you may create some string here to alert user
 echo "Data nim"; echo " "; echo $key['nipd'] ; echo " ";  echo "Sudah Ada"; echo '<br>'; 
}else {
   //other logics here
echo "Data nim"; echo " "; echo $key['nipd'] ; echo " ";  echo "Sudah Masuk"; echo '<br>';
}
}
$this->db->update('temp_mahasiswa',$tambah);

$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Comment: break you big array data into small array chuck and then insert

Comment: edited my post, I tried that before but still not fix this, after 30 seconds it's ended

Answer (score 0):

### Way 1

You can insert data with `LOAD DATA`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

it is much faster than `INSERT`.

### Way2

You can create queue (for example with Beanstalk) and background job what will insert data.